# Maison de maître

Tags: terminologie, locutions

Qu'est-ce l'expression *maison de maître* désigne exactement ?

L'expression est assez utilisée dans le domaine de l'immobilier en France et correspond à un certain type de maison à acheter / vendre. Néanmoins, elle me paraît designer une chose assez différente de [la description qu'on trouve dans Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maison_de_ma%C3%AEtre) - à mon avis les maisons de cet article paraîtraient plutôt sous la désignation de *manoir* ou de *château*.

Plus spécifiquement, quand on parle d'une *maison de maître* :

- S'agit il d'un type ou une période de construction spécifique ? Par exemple, peut-on appeler ainsi une maison construite il y a 20-30 ans ?
- Peut-on appeler ainsi une chaumière ou une maison en bois ?
- Qui est *le maître* ici : le propriétaire ou le constructeur ?
- Peut-on appeler ainsi une maison en location (dont les habitants ne sont pas les propriétaires de la maison) ?
- Est-ce que cette désignation est spécifique à certaines régions françaises ?

Comment: _Manoir_ pour moi implique que le propriétaire initial était noble, mais l'architecture peut être celle d'une maison de maitre. _Château_ a une origine militaire même s'il a dérive, est une taille au-dessus pour les complexes qui n'ont pas de fonction militaire. _Palais_ est plus urbain, sans fonction militaire, plutôt même avec une fonction administrative, donc plutôt pour la famille régnante et la très haute noblesse.

Comment: @Unfrancophone À mon avis, *château* en France est rarement une forteress - plutôt une grande maison avec un parc. Dans certain regions, comme Bordeaux, one appele *château* même une cabane... mais avec un vignoble.

Answer (score 1):

*Maison de maître* est une expression un peu désuète qui signifie qu'il s'agit d'une maison située en dehors d'une agglomération et construite pour un notable, un propriétaire terrien, une personne suffisamment aisée pour y héberger du personnel de maison. Cette maison est souvent devenue une résidence secondaire depuis le début du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, la principale se situant alors en ville.

Par son architecture, façade, ses dimensions, son petit escalier pour accéder à une porte d'entrée imposante, ses multiples cheminées, la hauteur sous plafond de son rez-de-chaussée, les matériaux utilisés, elle laisse transparaître la prospérité de son propriétaire.

1. On n'appelle plus vraiment les maisons contemporaines des maisons de maître, mais pourquoi pas. Il s'agit de marketing.
2. Une chaumière est historiquement une maison de cultivateurs plutôt pauvres. Elle est donc peu compatible avec la définition donnée ci-dessus. Une maison en bois peut en revanche être une maison de maître si elle "en impose" suffisamment, ou si elle est très ancienne et présente les autres caractéristiques requises.
3. Le maître dont il est question est le propriétaire initial de la maison.
4. Oui, tout le monde peut louer une maison de maître, comme on peut louer un château sans être chatelain.
5. Le terme n'est pas spécifique à une région particulière.

Comment: J'habite dans une petite ville normande et ce que des agents immobilier propose ici comme *maison de maître* est une maison dans la ville (sans beaucoup de terrain), normallement construite il y a 70-100 ans, en brique.  Ce n'est pas ce qu'on pourrait appeler *maison pauvre*, mais pas tros riche non plus (pas un manoir vraiment, même si on peut facilment avoir beacoup plus de terrain dans les villages dans alentours pour la même prix), en outre normalement elles demandent beaucoup de rénovation. Ca peut être l'exaggeration *marketing*, mais le terme paraît assez utilisé.

Comment: Le fait qu'une maison demande beaucoup de rénovation n'intervient pas dans le fait quelle puisse être qualifiée de maison de maître ou pas. Une maison de maître, un manoir ou un château peuvent très bien être en ruine. Si la maison n'est pas récente, qu'elle contient plus de pièces que la moyenne, plusieurs cheminées, si elle est bien en retrait par rapport à la rue, si un escalier donne accès à une porte d'entrée imposante, si elle est haute de plafond, on peut l'appeler ainsi. Si c'est une maison de plain-pied où la porte d'entrée donne dans la cuisine, non.

Comment: J'ai mentionné la rénovation seulement dans le contexte des *maison riche/pauvre*. Autrement, comme je l'avais déjà dit, les maisons qu'on m'a presenté dans cette appellation ne paraissaît particulairement hors normes ou hors prix pour n'importe quel acheteur d'un maison. Je repete qu'on ne parle pas ici de la région parisienne, ou la prix d'un appartement est celle d'un chateau à Normandie.

Comment: @RogerVadim Pour moi équivalent urbain de la maison de maitre est l'hôtel particulier. Dans les deux cas, ce sont des bâtiments suffisamment vaste pour non seulement loger le propriétaire, mais son personnel de maison au moins en partie, souvent des invités et en prime avoir une vie mondaine avec des pièces assez grandes pouvant être réservées à cet usage (il y a naturellement des différences architecturales dictées par la situation). (Bon, les agents immobiliers ont une tendance certaine à utiliser les termes de manière inflationniste, et j'avoue qu'ils sont suivis par l'usage).

Comment: @guillaume31 Oui, j'aurais tendance à les nommer "hôtels particuliers" mais rien n'interdit de dire "maison de maître" si c'est traditionnel dans la région, le terme n'a de toute façon pas de définition légale contraignante. J'ai d'ailleurs trouvé cette [maison](https://fr.luxuryestate.com/p91140345-maison-de-luxe-en-vente-rivesaltes) que je n'appellerai pas hôtel-particulier à cause du style méridional et pour laquelle *maison de maître* me semble acceptable malgré certains manques. Les constructions attenantes sont probablement postérieures.

Answer (score 1):

En Belgique (peut-être dans certaines villes françaises ?), "maison de maître" désigne souvent une maison de ville de standing - acollée à d'autres, habitat mitoyen très développé oblige.

Même s'il n'existe [pas de définition stricte](https://www.lesoir.be/art/505974/article/economie/immo/2014-03-27/differentes-vies-d-une-maison-maitre) et que les professionnels de l'immobilier usent généreusement du terme, elle date souvent du début du XXè siècle et se distingue de "l'hôtel de maître" par sa façade moins large et son absence de porte cochère.

Le maître en question est le propriétaire originel de la demeure, même si le cas de figure le plus fréquent aujourd'hui est une maison de maître découpée en appartements loués ou possédés par des personnes différentes.